# Expo Document picker does not give back the correct uri

Tags: react-native, expo

So I am trying to use the expo document picker (https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/document-picker/) to let the user select an image from their phones file system and display it on the screen. It was working quite recently until I noticed that the promise it sends back stopped returning the correct uri. Before it was returning a uri starting with `file:///data/` where as now it returns a uri starting with `/data`. This new type of uri does not display on the screen and I am wondering how I get back to the old one? I am using `await DocumentPicker.getDocumentAsync` to get the file in the first place.

Comment: Check out [this](https://snack.expo.io/@kartikeyvaish/document-picker-example) snack. Let me know if you get the desired result by this.

Comment: Thanks, it works

Comment: nvm its not a code issue it's an import/library version thing. There were some warnings about document picker and a few other libraries and as soon as I updated them it went back to the /data URI format.

Comment: Even prepending "file//" is not working - I am having the same issue after updating from expo SDK 38 to SDK 42

Answer (score 4):

I had the exact same problem after upgrading from expo 38 to 42. I did a workaround using `expo-file-system`.

First I set the `copyToCacheDirectory` option to false

```
const result = await DocumentPicker.getDocumentAsync({
        type:'*/*',
        copyToCacheDirectory: false,
      });
```

That would save the file to the `conten://` [file space](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem/). Once we have the file we can copy it to our `file://` location:

```
const uri = FileSystem.documentDirectory+result.name;

await FileSystem.copyAsync({
   from: result.uri,
   to: uri
})
```

Now you should be able to use uri (which includes the file:// path) without problems.

Answer (score 2):

I have same problem from expo SDK 38 to SDK 42,
I find a workaround from [here](https://giters.com/expo/expo/issues/13627)

```
const encode = uri => {
  if (Platform.OS === 'android') return encodeURI(`file://${uri}`)
  else return uri
}
...
<Button 
  onPress = { async () => {
    let result = await DocumentPicker.getDocumentAsync({ type: '*/*' })
    if (result.type === "success") {
      console.log("getDocumentAsync", result);
      Alert.alert(
        "upload file",
        `Whether to upload ${result.name}`,
        [
          {
            text: "Cancel",
            onPress: () => {},
            style: "cancel"
          },
          { 
            text: "OK", 
            onPress: () => dispatch(action.sendFile(encode(result.uri))) 
          }
        ],
        { cancelable: true }
      )
    }
  }}
/>
```

it work for me!

Answer (score 0):

I you want the file to be accessible for using in WebView, You can do this

```
const result = await DocumentPicker.getDocumentAsync({
     type: "application/pdf",
     copyToCacheDirectory: false,
   });
```

This is will give you a uri like this

```
{
...,
"uri": "content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/home%3Ayour-file.pdf",
}
```

and you can access the file by passing it as uri

```
{{
          uri: uri,
        }}
```